# web browser engine to embed in win32 program

Tags: winapi, browser, chromium, chromium-embedded

I need to put in simple Win32 program kind of ability to view web pages. It must be just window with page in it, no browser adress bars or other elements, just working web page in win32 window without any standart browser elements.
It seems that i need some kind of project, that gives me some way to embed chromium engine (chromium most likely) in to win32 api, and, obviously, give the full controls over the messages and other stuff that going to that "browser" window. I was looking at CEF project http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/ , but will it fit, or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

My (unfortunate) suggestion is to use `IWebBrowser2` if you just want to use the Internet Explorer control.

Example can be seen here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16559/Launch-and-control-MSIE-using-IWebBrowser2

Comment: But I forgot to mention, that I need this stuff to be able to work with not only win32 but on mac os too, freely run on any clear system, and support all modern web technologies, and be as smooth as any modern browser (that means not IE)

Comment: @SinnerSmile: Suggest you use Qt then.  It has webkit embedded and the same code will work on Windows and Mac.    How would a Win32 application work on Mac anyway?

Comment: well, i need webkit to work, program side itself obviously will be different for different system, but it's going to be pretty simple that's why the main thing here is working webkit, thx for your suggestion, will look at it)

Comment: By the way at the end i was going with chromium embedded and it is working really great!